# Brake squeaks on 2013 Cruze

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, cruze

I was told that the brakes on the 2013 Chevy Cruze would squeak if the rotors had condensation etc. They had already resurfaced front rotors, adjusted and cleaned the rear pads and told me basically to live with it due to age of car (2013 with 43000 miles) and was all they could do. I have it in now for third visit and I do know that a service advisory has come out on this problem and they said it came out after I had my car in for service. Told them I would not pay for anymore work on brakes since I had already paid for the problem to be fixed

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi Don.  Do you have a question in there.  If you do, can your modify what you put down to form a question?  Thanks.

Comment: Got it fixed the Chevrolet dealer fixed for free and I guess because they messed up before when I took it in and they checked second time and missed the cause